# Is $\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \cup \left\{ 0\right\}$ closed set?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $\left\{  \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}  \cup \left\{ 0\right\}$ is closed set? I suppose that yes, but I have no idea how can I prove it.

Comment: I believe it's easier to show that the complement is open.

Comment: I was thinking so, but how prove that $\mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0,1,  \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3} ,  \frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{5},...  \right\} $ is open set?

Comment: I would like to see what you tried rather than 'i have no idea how i can prove it'. writing out the definition would be a good start.

Comment: did you try finding all limit points?

Comment: I don't know if this is too fancy, but it's easy to prove it's compact (an open set around $0$ contains all but finitely many of the points), and a compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: See also [Prove that $\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/665896)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : It would be a bit easy if you can realize :

$\big(\{ \frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}\big)^C=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\big(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big)\text{with} (-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)$

Comment: we have the same idea in this same time :)

Comment: good.. may be you could have spend some more time before posting this question though it is alright to get this idea after posting this :)

Answer (score 1):

I have any other idea:

We have $\mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0,1,  \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3} ,  \frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{5},...  \right\} = (- \infty, 0)  \cup (1,+ \infty )  \cup  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(  \frac{1}{n+1} , \frac{1}{n} \right)$  so of course it must be open.

Answer (score 1):

**Showing that the set is closed.**
Say we have a sequence $x_n$ contained in the set $X = \left\{  \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}  \cup \left\{ 0\right\}$ that converges as a sequence in $\Bbb R$. Then there are two options:

1. It converges toward $0$. In this case, it converges to a point in $X$.
2. It converges to some real number $a \neq 0$. Then $x_n$ has to be constantly equal to $a$ from some $n$ on. We can see this because there is some $\epsilon'$ such that $|x_n - 0| \geq \epsilon'$ from some $n$ on. That means that there are only a finite number of points it can vary between, and they all have non-zero distance between them. Choose an $\epsilon$ smaller than the smallest of the distances, and we see that $x_n$ has to be eventually constant. Thus $a\in X$ and we are done.

So any sequence of points in $X$ that converges in $\Bbb R$, converges in $X$, and therefore $X$ is closed.

**Showing that the complement is open.**
Let $a \in \Bbb R \setminus X$. Then I claim that $\inf_{x\in X} |a - x| > 0$. First of all, let's define $\epsilon' = |a - 0|/3$. Then there are only finitely many points $x\in X$ so that $|x - 0| \geq \epsilon'$, so the value
$$
\epsilon'' = \min_{x\in X, |x| \geq \epsilon'}|a - x|
$$
is defined and greater than $0$ (since $a \not \in X$). Any $x$ not considered here has distance at least $3\epsilon'/2$ from $a$, by the triangle inequality and definition of $\epsilon'$.

Let $\epsilon = \min(\epsilon', \epsilon'')/2$. Then the $\epsilon$-ball around $a$ will contain no points of $X$. Since $a$ was arbitrary in the set $\Bbb R \setminus X$, this set must be open.

Comment: I had a more general form of this problem on my first analysis assignment at the university. Then $X$ was just the union of the points of a convergent sequence in a non-specified metric space, together with the limit. This argument still works in that case (it's a bit harder to use the topological arguments in the other answers when you don't have the intervals $\left(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$ to work with).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $\{ \frac{1}{n} \} \cup \{0\} = A $. Maybe if you can show that the closure $\overline{A} = A $, then $A$ must be closed.